# How to organise translation fields and commun fields using symfony a2lix and knp doctrine behaviors

Tags: symfony, field, formwizard, ergonomics, a2lix-translation

After a lot of research and your helps, I can use A2lix and KNP doctrine behaviors translation. All seems to work fine but...

I would like to organise my fields (those for translation and common).

How can I only have **ONE** tabMenu translation (EN|FR|NL) for my full entity. Until now I found this documentation ([How to order translated with not translated fields using doctrine knp translatable extentions with A2lix translation form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491040/how-to-order-translated-with-not-translated-fields-using-doctrine-knp-translatab)) but I always have Tabs for each translation field and no tab for those who does not need translation.

It's no really ergonomic I think. Is there a solution ?

It's quite important for me because if I had to do a wizard form for example. I don't think that it's common to see each languages tab for each translation fields.

I hope to be clear and that somebody have an answer, because I didn't find anything on Symfo and the bundles (a2lix, knp).

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want all languages in one tab or only one tab with one language?

Comment: One tab, one locale (e.g. FR) but what I would like is to only have on top (EN | FR | NL) and all fields (with translation needed and not translation needed) in the pannel-tab. So I can organise my fields (in the view) as I want.

Comment: The first thing that comes in my mind is to override the `a2lix_translations_widget` block located in `default.html.twig` resource file accordingly to your needs (or build a new one to use when and where you need this behavior). Now I haven't the time but I will take a look at this during the evening.

Comment: @gp_sflover : many thanks, I will also look for a solution.

Comment: I haven't had yet the time to go deeper into this argument (although I think the only solution is the one I wrote in my previous comment), but reading your question again I think that what you want to do is not very practical also because then you cannot identify anymore the "translatable" fields

Comment: @gp_sflover : Indeed but I need to find a solution because it's not ergonomic like that. Thank you for your precious advices.